# Imágenes locales en Angular

Tags: angular

Hola estoy empezando en Angular y quisiera saber si hay forma de colocar imágenes dentro del proyecto y colocarlas en el html de algún componente, como si fuera un archivo html. Es que estoy tratando de mostrarlas y sale un error.

Así, lo coloco dentro del archivo html de un componente y en consola me retorna un error. Cómo debo hacerlo para guardar imágenes dentro del mismo proyecto que tengo de Angular y mostrarlas en el html de algun componente?

Si coloco la url de una imagen sí que funciona pero una imagen local no puedo, no se porqué.  Muchas gracias por las respuestas.

`<img src="imagen.jpg" alt="">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es fácil simplemente pon tu imagen en la carpeta assets y llamas de esta forma:

```
 <img src="./assets/imagen.jpg"
```

Comment: jajaja eso si era simple, gracias amigo

Comment: De nada, a ti. Por favor si te parece correcta la respuesta puedes marcarla como correcta para otros usuarios que tengan la misma duda.

Comment: listo amigo gracias